# Including source files / javadoc comments in compiled JAR file using Bash scripting

Tags: java, bash, jar, javadoc

Here is my current bash script that lets you compile java sources to class files in the bin directory and then to copy it to a dedicated directory so imports won't be `import bin.library.Class` but just `import library.Class`. I've seen other threads, but they're either using Eclipse or running a java project while having JARs in a lib folder. *If you're wondering how to do that `java -cp 'bin/;lib/*' main.Main`*

**Current script that allows for compilation with class files**

```sh
javac -d bin $(find . -name "*.java")
cp -r ./bin/library ./library
jar cf0 TestLibrary.jar library/**/*.class
rm -r library
```

I know there is like `-uf` to add files to my JAR file, but adding the `src/**/*.java` files does not work at all. Essentially I want when I include my Java library in the `.classpath` using the line `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/TestLibrary.jar"/>` I want when I hover over a method I can see the Javadoc I have in my source files.

Comment: So what are you asking?  How to generate the javadoc?  How to include the generated javadoc in a JAR?  How to make your application browse / show the javadocs?  How to get an IDE to show it?  Please clarify.

Comment: By the way, the `jar` command doesn't do wildcard expansion, so `src/**/*.java` probably won't expand as you might hope it would.  The expansion is handled by your command shell.

Comment: @StephenC How would I include the javadoc in the jarfile, so that an IDE would show it yes. I know about the javadoc command to generate HTML variant, but that's not what I want

Comment: Well, an IDE doesn't look for javadocs.  It looks for Java source code, and produces extracts the document snippets on the fly.   And you typically don't put your source code in your main JAR file, you put it into a separate JAR (or ZIP) file to your compiled code.  But the answer is that you create the JAR / ZIP file like an ordinary one.  You prepare a list of all of the pathnames and  pass them to the `jar` command.  (Like the `jar` manual says ...)